# Whats a simple way to share non-trivial objects, say nested lists of dicts between views/templates per session in Python Flask.

Tags: python, flask

I cant use the session object, as I get an error on assignment saying these objects are non JSON serializable.

I did some digging, and it looks like caching is an option, but I am looking to go for a simpler/dirtier alternative if available.

Use case is based on certain user input, backend generates a bunch of tables represented as nested lists, which need to be stored somewhere, pending further user input to select which of these tables to view n render.

Fairly new to python/flask, and am looking for a workable approach, not necessarily a robust solution

Comment: I'm not sure why you would like to do this, but you're not supposed to pass complex data structures from views to templates. If you do, you'll end up coding control flows and data indexing with the templating language, but it is not designed for that. You'd be better off storing your objects in a database and structure them in such a way that it will need less processing when you pass it from views to templates.

Comment: Well, fair point.  I'm just getting a complex nested data structure from an external DB based on user input, ( list of tables as a report-deck).  And I want to present to the user a tabbed interface to select each of these available reports to go and render these tables. Not sure if this data is best stored in db.  My webapp using flask doesnt use sqlalchemy or a flask db presently, and I'm hoping to do without it

Comment: Did you check what in your data structure is not JSON serializable? If it is just lists and dicts there should not be a problem. A stack trace would be useful.